# The textfield in an UIAlertController should not be the first responder

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have an UIAlertController with a textfield in it, like this:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Hello, World!", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let someAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Action", style: .Default) { (_) in }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) {(_) in }

    alertController.addAction(someAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textfield in
        textfield.text = "Text"
    }

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When the controller is presented, the textfield has focus and the keyboard comes up. Is it possible to change that behavior so that the textfield only becomes first responder when the user taps on it? I don't want the keyboard to be presented at the same time the alert controller is presented.

Comment: I don't know if this will work but try using the `completion` block when presenting the alert controller to resign first responder on the text field.

Comment: I already tried that. But this causes the alert view to show with keyboard and than lets the keyboard slide down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one slightly hacky solution that involves associated objects and method swizzling.

The idea is to give `UITextField` a closure that gives outside classes a say in whether a text field can become the first responder or not. This closure passes back boolean value indicating whether the text field is trying to become the first responder due to user interaction or due to `canBecomeFirstResponder` having been programmatically called on the text field. It also passes back the value that `canBecomeFirstResponder` would return normally in the `defaultValue` parameter -- this isn't needed in this case, but as a general solution it could be useful to have.

First, we add the `UITextField` extension that will handle the swizzling and associated object stuff:

```
public extension UITextField {

    // Private struct to hold our associated object key
    private struct AssociatedKeys {
        static var HandlerKey = "xxx_canBecomeFirstResponder"
    }

    // Typealias for the type of our associated object closure
    public typealias CanBecomeFirstResponderHandler = (fromUserInteraction: Bool,
        defaultValue: Bool) -> Bool

    // We need this private class to wrap the closure in an object
    // because objc_setAssociatedObject takes an 'AnyObject', but
    // closures are not 'AnyObject's -- they are instead 'Any's
    private class AnyValueWrapper {
        var value: Any?
    }

    // Define the closure as a computed property and use associated objects to
    // store/retrieve it.
    public var canBecomeFirstResponderHandler: CanBecomeFirstResponderHandler? {
        get {
            // Get the AnyValueWrapper object
            let wrapper = objc_getAssociatedObject(self,
                                                   &AssociatedKeys.HandlerKey)

            // ...then get the closure from its `value` property
            return (wrapper as? AnyValueWrapper)?.value
                as? CanBecomeFirstResponderHandler
        }

        set {
            // If the new value is not nil:
            if let newValue = newValue {

                // Create a new AnyValueWrapper and set its `value` property to 
                // the new closure
                let wrapper = AnyValueWrapper()
                wrapper.value = newValue

                // Set this wrapper object as an associated object
                objc_setAssociatedObject(
                    self,
                    &AssociatedKeys.HandlerKey,
                    wrapper,
                    .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC
                )

                return
            }

            // If the new value is nil, remove any existing associated object for
            // the closure
            objc_setAssociatedObject(
                self,
                &AssociatedKeys.HandlerKey,
                nil,
                .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC
            )
        }
    }

    // Set up the method swizzling when the `UITextField` class is initialized
    public override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        // Make sure we are not in a subclass when this method is called
        if self !== UITextField.self {
            return
        }

        // Swizzle the canBecomeFirstResponder method.
        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            let originalSelector =
                #selector(UITextField.canBecomeFirstResponder)
            let swizzledSelector =
                #selector(UITextField.xxx_canBecomeFirstResponder)

            let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
            let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)

            let didAddMethod =
                class_addMethod(self,
                                originalSelector,
                                method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                                method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))

            if didAddMethod {
                class_replaceMethod(self, swizzledSelector,
                                    method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                                    method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
            }
            else {
                method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Method Swizzling

    // Our swizzled method that replaces the canBecomeFirstResponder 
    // method of `UITextField`
    func xxx_canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {

        // Get the default value of canBecomeFirstResponder
        let defaultValue = xxx_canBecomeFirstResponder()

        // If we have a closure in our associated object:
        if let canBecomeFirstResponder = canBecomeFirstResponderHandler {

            // Determine if the user interacted with the text field and set
            // a flag if so. We do this by checking all gesture recognizers
            // of the text field to see if any of them have begun, changed, or
            // ended at the time of calling `canBecomeFirstResponder`.
            // It's reasonable to assume that if `canBecomeFirstResponder` is
            // called when any of these conditions are true, then the text field
            // must be trying to become the first responder due to a user
            // interaction.
            var isFromUserInteraction = false
            if let gestureRecognizers = gestureRecognizers {
                for gestureRecognizer in gestureRecognizers {
                    if (gestureRecognizer.state == .Began ||
                        gestureRecognizer.state == .Changed ||
                        gestureRecognizer.state == .Ended)
                    {
                        isFromUserInteraction = true
                        break
                    }
                }
            }

            // Call our closure and pass in the two boolean values,
            // then return the result
            return canBecomeFirstResponder(
                fromUserInteraction: isFromUserInteraction,
                defaultValue: defaultValue
            )
        }

        // If we don't have a closure in our associated object,
        // just return the original value
        return defaultValue
    }
}
```

Then, you can use this closure in your alert controller text field configuration handler like so:

```
alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textfield in
    textfield.text = "Text"

    // Set the closure on the text field. You can use the passed in flags if you
    // want or you can simply return fromUserInteraction to only allow user
    // interaction to let the text field become the first responder, as is done
    // here:
    textfield.canBecomeFirstResponderHandler = {
        fromUserInteraction, defaultValue in
        return fromUserInteraction
    }
}
```

---

### Old solution that no longer works:

Adding this:

```
alertController.view.endEditing(true)
```

right before presenting the alert controller will resign first responder from all text fields and prevent the keyboard from appearing while presenting.

Answer (score 2):

I used a much simpler trick. I created a boolean called canEdit and set it to NO, and only set it to YES in the completion of the "present view controller" method. In the textfield should begin editing, i set a condition based on the canEdit boolean whether to return YES or NO. Here is my code:

```
@interface ViewController (){

    BOOL canEdit; 

}

-(void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
mentorAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Magen David Students" message:@"Hi! Please select your mentor!" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            [mentorAlert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {

                textField.placeholder = @"Mentor";
                textField.delegate = weakSelf;
                textField.tag = 200;
                textField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


            }];

            [self presentViewController:mentorAlert animated:YES completion:^{

                canEdit = YES;


            }];



}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
if(textField.tag == 200){

    if (!canEdit)
            return NO;
else
return YES;
}
}
```